# Javax.sound.midi studying code not working on MacOS X

Tags: java

I'm trying to run code importing classes from `javax.sound.midi` package, but nothing works. Code had compiled and run successfully, but there is no sound. 
I've download soundbank for Java, and put it in `audio` folder, but it's still not working.

Macbook Pro mid 2010

Mac OS X High Sierra

Java version `12.0.1` from 2019-04-16

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;


public class MiniMiniMusicApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);

            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
            track.add(noteOff);

            player.setSequence(seq);

            player.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use command 128 for both `a` and `b`. Base on [ShortMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/ShortMessage.html) the command 128 is note off event.

- 144  Note On Event
- 128  Note Off Event
- 192  Program Change for changing default instrument etc
- 176  Control change for sending events
- 224  Pitch Bend

As example change the `a.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);` with `a.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, 44, 100);` and you will get sound.

```
public static void play() {
    try {
        Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        player.open();

        Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);

        Track track = seq.createTrack();

        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, 44, 100);
        MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 5);
        track.add(noteOn);

        ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
        b.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 1, 44, 100);
        MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
        track.add(noteOff);

        player.setSequence(seq);

        player.start();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```